# Please help me to refine code of a simple function

Tags: c#

I want to write a simple function, which is to check is there a file in specified dictionary which should use recursive way to check

The function is simple, but my code looks stupid.

Can you help me to refine the code a little bit more beautiful...

```
private bool SearchFileInFolder(string baseURL, string fileName)
    {
        bool result = true;
        List<string> dictionaries = new List<string>(Directory.GetDirectories(baseURL));
        foreach (string dic in dictionaries)
        {
            if (File.Exists(dic + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fileName))
                result = false;
            else
                result = SearchFileInFolder(dic, fileName);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Can I use Parallel.ForEach to make the function more efficient ? But the function is a recursive function, so ....

Comment: Why do you find it stupid?

Comment: By the way, is this working? `result` is over-written each itteration...

Comment: @Liel - maybe because it tries to re-implement built in function - [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Why would you name a variable `dictionaries` when you're assigning it the return value of `GetDirectories`? It's clearly not a list of dictionaries.

Comment: In the future, you may wish to use [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @MattJohnson - note that CodeReview is for working code... So far it does something strange (due to overwriting `result` on recursion) which most people will consider "does not perform stated function"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this overloaded method:

```
public static string[] GetFiles(
    string path,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption
)
```

You can give the option to search in all subdirectories, that way you don't need to do it manually.